# Why okhttp request return socket exception immediately regardless of my timeout setting 5000ms?

Tags: http, okhttp

I got the following socket timeout exception immediately when I send the http request to spring boot server. During that period of time, our springboot server was receiving several http requests(More than 200 requests during keep alive interval time 15000ms). My question is:

1. Why socket timeout exception occur regardless of my timout setting 5000ms?
2. Is this caused by connection reuse during the keep alive time?

My okhttp is inited as the following code.

```java
// class field definition 
    private static final int      CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE    = 200;
    private static final long     KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_MILLIS  = 15000;
    private static final int      timeoutMs = 5000;

// init method
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .connectionPool(
                        new ConnectionPool(CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                    .writeTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();
```

```java
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(Okio.kt:159)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit$jvm(AsyncTimeout.kt:203)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:163)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:349)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:222)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:210)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:181)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:105)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:82)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
```

Comment: Can you create an executable test case for this? We don't see it elsewhere but it's possible there's something special in your config.

Comment: @JesseWilson It occur in our production environment, I will try my best to reproduce the issue. I will add more detailed info if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JesseWilson It is caused by reuse a invalid connection. I anwer my question myself. You can check. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you can isolate this, we can fix it in the OkHttp project. I've never seen pooled connections trigger timeouts like this so the reproduction would be very helpful.

Comment: @JesseWilson It is in our production environment and many dependencies are involved, so I can't reproduce it very fast but I will try later in my free time. I can give you more information. We now just adjust the config value to avoid this case. We set keep alive time smaller than the socket timeout value and read/write timeout value to ensure the timeout connection will never be reused when it is timeouted. We will keep observing whether the issue will reappear again.

Comment: @JesseWilson  I check okhttp's source code and know it will check connection is healthy before reuse it. Is there any situation that the healthy check logic not cover like the halfopen connection?

Comment: @JesseWilson By the way, my okhttp version is 4.2.2 which I think is a relatively new version. Another tip is that the connection count and idle connection count is zero in my output logs when this immediately sockettimeout exception is throw.

Comment: Use the absolute latest version?

Answer (score 2):

It is because connection pool will reuse the invalid connection. For example, the connection's first use meet the socket timeout exception and it will be put into connection pool again to avoid tcp hand shake when build connection. When the next time we use the connection(We set keep alive to 15s, so it is still in the connection pool), it will throw sockettimeout exception immediately

Comment: Any idea about how to fix this?